# Union of multiple tables with different number of columns, ordered by another table to get the changed columns name

Tags: mysql, union

I am trying to merge multiple tables, with a range of dates, together into one table. Most tables follow the same column names, but some tables don't have that column or their Names were changed. These tables have common columns and there may only be one-two of those columns that has a change of name and needs to be updated. I want to use a Union query to multiple tables (base on column names) where we compare a one tables column name with another table (OLD and New column Names are compared in the initial table).
Example:
Multiple Tables for Union:

Table_1

```
|Date          | New Name1 | New Name2 | OLD Name3 | New NameN |

|1/1/2008  | 73.2               | 43.2               | 33.2                | 13.2                |

|1/2/2008  | 13.2               | 23.2               | empty               | 53.2                |

|1/3/2008  | 23.2               | 33.2               | 13.2                | 73.2                |

|X/X/2008 | ………               | …….               | ……..                | ……..                |
```

Table_2

```
|Date          | New Name1 | New Name2 | NEW Name3 | OLD Name4  | New NameN |

|1/1/2010  | 12.6               | 13.6               | 23.6                | 13.6                | 13.6              

|1/2/2010  | 14.6               | 33.6               | 14.6                | 53.6                | 17.6                 



|X/X/2010 | ………               | …….               | ……..                | ……..               |
```

Table_3

```
|Date          | New Name1 | New Name2 | NEW Name3 | NEW Name4 | New NameN |

|1/1/2013  | 12.2               | 19.2               | 24.2                | 17.2                | 14.2 

|1/2/2013  | 24.2               | 23.2               | 15.2                | 43.2                | 17.2                 

|1/3/2013  | empty               | 31.6               | 44.2                | 77.2               | 16.2                 

|X/X/2013 | ………               | …….               | ……..                | ……..               |
```

Table_N

```
|Date          | New Name1 | New Name2 | NEW Name3 | OLD Name4  | New NameN |

|1/1/2018  | 32.4               | 13.4               | 23.4                | 43.4                | 13.4

|1/2/2018  | 14.4               | 33.4               | 14.4                | 53.4                | 17.4                 

|1/3/2018  | 23.4               | 31.4               | empty               | 77.4                | 16.4                 

|X/X/2018 | ………               | …….               | ……..                | ……..               |
```

Initial table: Column Names Comparison

```
|Name OLD    | Name New   |

|OLD Name1 | NEW Name1 |

|OLD Name2 | NEW Name2 |
|OLD Name3 | NEW Name3 |

|OLD Name4 | NEW Name4 |

|OLD NameN | NEW NameN |
```

Expected results of combination information from multiple MySQL tables. The columns of different tables are compared – if I can get them to match with the same name across multiple tables ordered by Initial Table (e.g. OLD Name3 = NEW Name3) the columns are United in the merged table; the columns that some table does not have are put into column list in merged table. Means the new created table should be a merged result of multiple tables based on their column name, containing all the data from same columns name and results come from the names of corresponding columns that not have the same names.

Merged Table

```
|Date          | New Name1 | New Name2 | NEW Name3 = | OLD Name4 = | New NameN |

                                  |   OLD Name3   | New Name4    | New NameN |

|1/1/2008  | 73.2          | 43.2               | 33.2                | 13.2      |…………………… |

|1/1/2010  | 12.6          | 13.6               | 23.6                | 13.6      | 13.6     

|1/3/2018  | 23.4               | 31.4               | empty             | 77.4                    


|X/X/2018 | ………               | …….               | ……..                | ……..          |
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a quick glance this looks like poor table design.  Why not just maintain a single table here to store all names?

Comment: Is there a naming convention which applies to your tables?

Comment: Let me see if I have understood - you have an unknowable number of tables? which have an unknowable number of columns? where columns may have been renamed from 1 table to another (but the relationships between the column names are maintained by hand in a cross reference table)? and the columns may or may not exist in all tables (eg col3 exists in table 1 but no other table)?And you want to create a table/virtual table with the columns in an unspecified order (no idea how you could do this given the column names are unknowable)

Comment: Is it possible that old name1 could be renamed a number of times eg old name1 = aaa newname 1 - bbb , newname1 -ccc, newname1  = ddd? AND can oldname1 and newname1 appear in the same table?

Comment: Union multiple table with different columns (names of stations) is ordered by date from 1/12008 to 1/1/2019. Names of each tables `PM25__RAW" + str(year) + "__1h`. All tables contain almost the same columns Date | Station 1 | Station 2 | Station N|. Each year number of stations (columns) was changed (added new or closed previous) from the year 2013 Names of some stations (colums) was changed. The changed names need to be updated from cross reference table.

Answer (score 0):

In union you can have n number of columns from n number of tables.But every table should have same columns.You can get the desired result using alias,if some table do not have the desired column that exist in any table and you need it then use can use '' as col_name.Here is the sample code

```
    select * from(
SELECT DATE col1,New Name1 as col2,New Name2 as col3,OLD Name3 as col4,'' as col5,New NameN as col6
from Table_1
UNION
SELECT DATE col1,New Name1 as col2,New Name2 as col3,NEW Name3 as col4,OLD Name4 as col5,New NameN as col6
from Table_2
UNION
SELECT DATE col1,New Name1 as col2,New Name2 as col3,NEW Name3 as col4,OLD Name4 as col5,New NameN as col6
from Table_3
UNION
SELECT DATE col1,New Name1 as col2,New Name2 as col3,NEW Name3 as col4,OLD Name4 as col5,New NameN as col6
from Table_N
) T1
```